# oAuth handling in Angular Frontend

Tags: python, angular, fastapi

I have a Python FastAPI Backend which gives me an endpoint in order to retrieve some oAuth data. The Endpoint works when i put it manually in my Browser. It first does a redirect retrieves an accessToken which it then adds to a second link and opens it. So the functionality works. Now i'm a bit stuck on how to get this data in my Frontend. I tried a GET request on the original endpoint but then get the response with the redirect link. What would be a clever way to handle this? I would like to store the data in the Frontend in order to manipulate it

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing many OAuth2 interactions, I recommend you use a library; OAuth2 flow is fairly complicated with the interactions between Client, Backend, Identification, & Authorization servers. Using a library helps ensure you are doing all the key swaps properly and securely; Also it will save you lots of time :).

Here is a library I would use in your shoes; https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to initiate the sample login form, i will now try further to solve my original problem, but i think it should be possible with this library.

Comment: Word Up!! Good job and get the loot.